# Unable to locate element. I am using protractor java script. I have several methods like css, xpath and id

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
<a class="menu-item-link transition" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-animation="false" data-container=".vertical-menu-tooltip-place" data-original-title="Passengers" id="link3">
    <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
    <span class="menu-title">Passengers</span>
</a>
```

I have tried using `id` but its not working. I even tried using x path but still no luck. I am getting error message that no locator found. This is the HTML code. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you describe which element you exactly wanna locate and what code you already have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to find the span with the text 'Passengers'. Here are several ways to do this:

```
element(by.css('span.menu-title')); //assumes the span is unique
element(by.css('a.menu-item-link i.fa-user-o span.menu-title')); //More specific if needed
element(by.css('a#link3 span')); //Using Id
```

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) has  a good list of css selector for reference. Also, `$('selector');` is the same as `element(by.css('selector'));` which is a useful shortcut when you are using it alot.

Answer (score 0):

If the tag element are static and unique then, You could try

```
element(by.css[a(data-original-title="Passengers"]));
```

Assuming the directive values aren't static unique values, where everything is Auto generated in run time, You can try out `element(by.xpath(//span[.='Passengers']));`

It's worth to check to which tag the inspect element actually points to. If it's span, I would suggest you to go with xpath. If it's `<a>`, then I would suggest you to go with CSS.

If neither CSS / xpath couldn't identify the elements, then I suppose your page isn't angular and I would suggest you to include

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

at the beginning of your test followed by any of the selectors.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It is better now to use

`browser. waitForAngularEnabled(false)`
instead of

`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`
<http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled>

Comment: its not working. i have tried everything. but still no element found and my website is angular.

Comment: element(By.xpath("//a[@id='link3']")).click();
//element(By.xpath("//a[@class='menu-item-link transition active-link' and @data-original-title='Passengers']")).click();
//element(by.css('.a[(data-original-title="Passengers"]')).click();
//element(By.xpath("//a[@class='menu-item-link transition' and @id='link3']")).click();....i tried with all  these selectors

Comment: am also trying to locate element using get(2) but shows error 'index out of bound'...element.all(By.css('.menu-item-link.transition')).get(2).click();